# Получения скриншота с двух мониторов

Tags: c#, screenshots

Как можно получить изображение с компьютера, имеющим два монитора? Ибо

```
Graphics graph = null;
var bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Получает скрин только с основного монитора

Comment: Не знаю, у меня сразу два скриншотит.

Comment: @VladSpirin, а они у вас в каком режиме работают?

Comment: вкратце: 1) делать снимок всего [виртуального экрана SystemInformation.VirtualScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen(v=vs.110).aspx), который охватывает экраны всех мониторов (возможно, с чёрной пустотой), а потом вырезать нужный; либо 2)выбрать из [всех имеющихся экранов Screen.AllScreens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx) и получить его границы (на виртуальном, вроде бы).

Answer (score 0):

Тема старая, но может кому понадобится.
Все дело в строке
graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
где 0, 0, 0, 0 это координаты откуда и куда, а size - сколько.
я сделал немного по другому, представь что скрин с двух экранов представляет собой единое полотно, тогда захват нужного изображения можно воспользоваться ф-ей:

```cs
private Bitmap GetScreenShot(int widht, int height, Point pLT)
{
    Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(widht, height);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(pLT, new Point(0, 0), printscreen.Size);
    return printscreen;
}
```

widht, height размеры изо, которое нужно захватить.
где pLT - это координата в нашем едином полотне, с которой начинать (левый верхний угол), вторая точка это (0, 0) это точка с которой рисовать например в picturebox'e

Comment: а для определения где какой монитор используйте Screen. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: height или heigth? widht или width?